# Bears with Unique Patterns

Tags: probability

I'm working with a probability problem related to assigning bears scarves with
unique patterns. Imagine that I have bears on a path that each have a scarf
with a given pattern. Say there exists 550 patterns available. I'm working with
a problem related to figuring out the probability that in a random sample of
bears, there are at least two bears with matching scarves. In particular, I
want to figure out when this probability is 1. I solved this by solving for
the complement in the general case, i.e. when we have $n$ bears in our sample,
$$1-P(\text{no match}) = 1- \frac{\frac{550!}{(550-n)!}}{550^{n}},$$
But when I set this equal to 1, i get
$$\frac{\frac{550!}{(550-n)!}}{550^{n}} = 0,$$
and I believe that this equality cannot hold given the construction of the
probability. Have I perhaps counted this probability wrong?

Comment: For probability $1$, it is $551$.  Of course much earlier the probability will be nearly $1$, that is, $1$ for all practical purposes.

Comment: For good estimates of probabilities, we need to know the distribution of scarf patterns. I would expect the $550$ patterns to be far from equally  likely.

Comment: Does my answer answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any number of bears up to $550$, there is a nonzero probability that they all have different scarf patterns, so of course the probability that at least two of them have the same scarf patterns is strictly less than one. This agrees with the fact that your fraction is never zero for any integer $n$ from $0$ to $550$ inclusive.

Note also that your formula is not valid in the case when there are more than $550$ bears, and unless you know all about meromorphic functions, you cannot say that $(-1)! = \infty_\mathbb{\hat{C}}$ just to make the formula 'work'.

When there are more than $550$ bears, it is obvious that surely at least two will have the same scarf, so in probabilistic terms this event has probability $1$.